# Tensor product of quadratic number field with itself

Tags: number-theory, extension-field, tensor-products

If $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$, is there a nice structure to $F\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} F$?

A spanning set of that tensor product is $1\otimes 1$, $1\otimes \sqrt{D}$, $\sqrt{D}\otimes 1$, and $\sqrt{D}\otimes\sqrt{D}$. I think these are linearly independent, since $\sqrt{D}\notin\mathbb{Q}$. In fact, if I write them as matrices (with respect to the previous basis, in order), I get that

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & D & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & D\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & D & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & D\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & D^2 \\ 0 & 0 & D & 0\\ 0 & D & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

All of these are full-rank, actually. I tried checking whether an arbitrary linear combination of these can have determinant 0, but I couldn't solve the resulting equation.

Based on another question, I can map $F\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} F\rightarrow F$ by $x\otimes y\mapsto xy$, and by dimensionality this has a kernel of dimension 2. In fact I can find a basis of this kernel: $1\otimes\sqrt{D}-\sqrt{D}\otimes 1$ and $\sqrt{D}\otimes\sqrt{D} - D\otimes 1$. So this has a non-trivial ideal, so it is not a field, but it seems to be an integral domain. Is there much more I can say about it?

Comment: What is $D$? The matrices correspond to the left multiplication operators of the elements in the list, written w.r.t. the basis? The question is still unclear. How should we say "much more" about the ring $$R=\Bbb Q[X,Y]\ /\ (X^2-D,Y^2-D)\ ?$$ The basis over $\Bbb Q$ is $1,X,Y,XY$, and from $0=D-D=(X^2-Y^2)=(X-Y)(X+Y)$ it seems that we also have divisors of zero...

Comment: dan_fulea, thanks, I don't know why I missed a difference of squares. Since $(\sqrt{D}\otimes 1)^2=(1\otimes\sqrt{D})^2$ and $(\sqrt{D}\otimes\sqrt{D})^2 = (D\otimes 1)^2)$, that gives enough information about the zero-divisors. These can give an isomorphism to $F\oplus F$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a very nice description of $F\otimes_{\mathbb Q} F$, and, more generally, $E\otimes_k F$ where $k$ is a field, $E$ is a finite separable extension, and $F$ is an arbitrary field extension.

In the simple case of the question,
$$
{\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{D})\otimes_{\mathbb Q} {\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{D}
\;\approx\; 
\mathbb Q[x]/\langle x^2-D\rangle \otimes_{\mathbb Q} \mathbb Q(\sqrt{D})
\;\approx\;
\mathbb Q(\sqrt{D})[x]/\langle x^2-D\rangle
$$
$$
\approx\; 
\mathbb Q(\sqrt{D})[x]/\langle x-\sqrt{D}\rangle
\oplus \mathbb Q(\sqrt{D})[x]/\langle x+\sqrt{D}\rangle
\;\approx\; \mathbb Q(\sqrt{D}) \oplus \mathbb Q(\sqrt{D})
$$
The more general version uses the obvious analogous argument.

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ and $W$ are two finite dimensional $k$-vector spaces with bases $B_V = \{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ and $B_W = \{w_1, \dots, w_k\}$ then a basis of $V\otimes_k W$ is

$$ B_{V\otimes_k W} = \{v_i\otimes w_j : 1\le i\le n, 1\le j\le k\}$$

So since quadratic number fields are $2$ dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces and $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ has basis $\{1, \sqrt{D}\}$ then you immediately get that $\{1\otimes 1, 1\otimes\sqrt{D}, \sqrt{D}\otimes 1, \sqrt{D}\otimes \sqrt{D}\}$ is a basis of $F\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} F$ as a $4$-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. No need to solve any annoying $4\times 4$ matrices.

As for further structure I'm not $100\%$ sure, but I hope this appropriately answers at least the first part of your question so as to be posted here rather than as a comment.